# Android Executing HTTP Post

Tags: java, android, apache, http

So I am trying to connect my chat application to a server, I am using this code, but the problem with this code is that it is using hardcoded message such as "And Dev is cool" but I have a text field where I can enter my message and send that to the server, How do I change the code so it takes input from user and not hardcoded messages?

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a to add an EditText to your xml view. then do

```
 EditText yourText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.'your edit text id');
```

You should have a button that the user clicks when they've entered their text that then launches the thread for internet and gets  `editText.getText()` to send into the HTTP

Comment: @aldito2 : That should be editText.getText().toString(). The getText() method of EditText returns an Editable and not a String.

Comment: you owuld have to declare it in the main class and then add the button to send to start thread. The edittext will have to be global, and you can do the `getText` method anywhere before you send it in. So, `
String STRINGYOUMADE = editText.getText();
nameValuePairs.add("stringdata", STRINGYOUMADE);`

as Squonk said `editText.getText().toString();`

Comment: why do you have to keep "stringdata"?

Comment: you don't have to. That can be named whatever you want it to be named. "stringdata" is the key for that data in the list and the other part is the value.